# How to send different parameters to same function for show/hide

Tags: angular

I have three password input box with buttons on click  I just need to show or hide the type of password(text or password) using fontawosme icon.

Below is the code which I tried as the code:

ts.file

```js
changePasswordType(type) {
  if (type == 'oldPassword') {
    this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;
    this._pwdType = this.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'
  } else if (type == 'newPassword') {
    this.newPassword = !this.newPassword;
    this._pwdType = this.newPassword ? 'text' : 'password'
  } else {
    this.confirmPassword = !this.confirmPassword;
    this._pwdType = this.confirmPassword ? 'text' : 'password'

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group position-relative">
  <label for="oldpassword" class="lable-title mb-0">Old Password</label>
  <input [type]="_pwdType" class="form-control" required name="old_password" [(ngModel)]="form.old_password" #old_password="ngModel" id="oldpassword">
  <button class="position-absolute hide-password" *ngIf="!showPassword" (click)="changePasswordType('oldPassword')">
              <i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i>
            </button>
  <button class="position-absolute hide-password " *ngIf="showPassword" (click)="changePasswordType('oldPassword')">
              <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
            </button>
</div>


<div class="form-group position-relative">
  <label for="newpassword" class="lable-title mb-0">New Password</label>
  <input [type]="_pwdType" class="form-control" required name="password" [(ngModel)]="form.password" #password="ngModel" id="newpassword">
  <button class="position-absolute hide-password" *ngIf="!newPassword" (click)="changePasswordType('newPassword')">
              <i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i>
            </button>
  <button class="position-absolute hide-password " *ngIf="newPassword" (click)="changePasswordType('newPassword')">
              <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
            </button>
</div>


<div class="form-group position-relative">
  <label for="conformpassword" class="lable-title mb-0">Confirm Password</label>
  <input [type]="_pwdType" class="form-control" required name="confirm_password" [(ngModel)]="form.confirm_password" #confirm_password="ngModel" id="conformpassword">
  <button class="position-absolute hide-password" *ngIf="!confirmPassword" (click)="changePasswordType('confirmPassword')">
              <i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i>
            </button>
  <button class="position-absolute hide-password " *ngIf="confirmPassword" (click)="changePasswordType('confirmPassword')">
              <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
            </button>
</div>
```

When the button is clicked then the all three input box converting to type text or else to password. I just need when I click on one button then only that button should show type text or password and icon should change respectively

Comment: can you reproduce the on stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/ and share the link here

Comment: Just by looking at your code, i can see that you have used the same '_pwdType' for all 3 input types and then you are updating the value of `_pwdType`. it is obvious that it would reflect where ever it is referenced. 
may be you need to use unique field for every input

Comment: @dreamweiver, I just want to know from this is that without using different variables cant it be done as the code will also be lengthier.

Comment: you can refer to  @wandrille answer, he has made the logic concise and simple, infact you dont need even the varible `_pwdType` anymore

Comment: @dreamweiver, here is the link for the code  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdxhnu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't really understood the problem but a refacto will be:

in `.ts`

```
showPassword  = false;
```

and in `.html`

```
<input [type]="showPassword ? 'password':'text'">
<button (click)="showPassword  = !showPassword  ">
    <i [ngClass]="{'far fa-eye-slash': !showPassword  , 'far fa-eye': showPassword  }"></i>
</button>
```

Working Code on StackBlitz,https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-372rjc

Comment: i have added the problem

Comment: I have edited the solution with an input. I haven't checked the order of the tertnaire. But it's to give you the main idea.

Comment: the solution you have given is working perfectly fine, but if want to apply the same functionality for other two input then I need to use different variables on every input which I don't want to use it.

Comment: I they have a different way to work, you will have to do that. Or you can have an object which have the 3 passwordsShow in it. But for me, it's the same.

Comment: @vinuta: no, you don't have to, you can use the existing variable `showPassword` , `confirmPassword` and `newPassword` which you have already used in respective sections `*ngIF`.

Comment: Thank you very much for  the solution

Comment: @vinuta, if this post solved your problem, then could you accept it as answer